# Rails Engine creating a before_filter like method for all parent controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, rails-engines

I'm attempting to build a Rails Gem somewhere between Devise and CanCan. Not nearly as complex as Devise, but having views and a controller.

I've created a method to be added to the top of any controller of the parent app that needs it almost exactly like Devise's `before_action :authenticate_user!` and CanCan's `load_and_authorize_resource`

I need the method to `redirect_to` a path in my mounted routes if the requirements are not met.

```
  module MyEngine
    module ControllerAdditions
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      module ClassMethods
        def pin_verified
          current_user ||= nil
          @pinned = current_user.nil? ? nil : current_user
          redirect_to setup_mobiles_path unless @pinned && @pinned.verified?
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

and in my `spec/dummy/app/controllers/users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  pin_verified

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

`pin_verified` is getting called as it's supposed to but I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `setup_mobiles_path' for UsersController:Class
```

Any thoughts on how I should be doing this?

**==== edit ====**

I altered this now to raise a custom exception, but now I need to rescue that exception some how and redirect to the needed path.

```
def pin_verified
  current_user ||= nil
  @pinned = current_user.nil? ? nil : current_user
  unless @pinned && @pinned.verified?
    raise ValidatedPinExpired
  end
end
```

I tried adding this to the ApplicationController of my gem, but it doesn't seem to be hitting Controller at all.

```
module MyEngine
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    rescue_from Exception do |exception|
      Rails.logger.info "==== exception: #{exception} ===="
      redirect_to setup_mobiles_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your pin_verified method should be adding a filter (at the moment that code runs when the class is loaded - there is no request to redirect )

Comment: That doesn't seem like the error I'm getting though. It doesn't recognize the path itself. And if that is the issue then how do I do this?

Comment: Path helpers also not available in that context (since you don't need them normally) Sounds like your pin_verified method should be creating a before_action